# How to inject html using mustache

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, mustache

Following is my content:

```
const content = Testing mutache with html. click {{{link}}}.
```

Following is my mustache code:

```
Mustache.render(content, {link:'<a href="http://google.com">here</a>'});
```

On screen, it is rendering as :

```
Testing mutache with html. click <a href="http://google.com">here</a>.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried rendering the element inside an HTML template, rather than a string? I'm not sure, as the syntax seems correct.

Comment: I am not getting you... @ChrisB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you don't use the mustache in this way. To render HTML into a template you would have to use the rawHTML method as described here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

to Quote "The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive"